# SIMD store intrinsic into std::vector causes Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, x86, simd, avx

I have a function which does the following -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <immintrin.h>

typedef struct{
    std::vector<double> x;
    std::vector<double> y;

    void reserve(size_t size){
        x.reserve(size);
        y.reserve(size);
    }

    size_t size(){
        return x.size();
    }
} Points2D;


void triangulate_simd(Points2D* points){

__m256d A_avx2 = _mm256_set1_pd(1.5542315);
__m256d B_avx2 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.974578234);
__m256d C_avx2 = _mm256_set1_pd(9.9937);
__m256d D_avx2 = _mm256_set1_pd(8.8773);
__m256d negative_ones = _mm256_set1_pd(-1);

    std::vector<double> X; 
    std::vector<double> Y; 
    std::vector<double> Z; 

    auto X_data = X.data();
    auto Y_data = Y.data();
    auto Z_data = Z.data();

    auto pts_x = points->x.data(); 
    auto pts_y = points->y.data();

    X.reserve(points->x.size()); 
    Y.reserve(points->x.size()); 
    Z.reserve(points->x.size());

    auto q = size_t(points->x.size() / 8);
    //std::cout<<q<<std::endl;

    for(size_t i=0; i < q; i+=4){
       // std::cout<<i<<"  ";

        __m256d pts_x_simd = _mm256_loadu_pd(pts_x + i);
        __m256d pts_y_simd = _mm256_loadu_pd(pts_y + i);
        
          __m256d result_z = _mm256_div_pd(_mm256_mul_pd(D_avx2, negative_ones), 
            _mm256_add_pd(C_avx2, _mm256_add_pd(
                _mm256_mul_pd(B_avx2, pts_y_simd), _mm256_mul_pd(A_avx2, pts_x_simd)
            )));  // Z = -D / (C + B*pt_y + A*pt_b)

        _mm256_storeu_pd(Z_data + i, result_z);
        _mm256_storeu_pd(X_data + i, _mm256_mul_pd(_mm256_loadu_pd(pts_x + i), result_z));
        _mm256_storeu_pd(Y_data + i, _mm256_mul_pd(_mm256_loadu_pd(pts_y + i), result_z));
        
    }

    for(size_t i = q*8; i < points->x.size(); i++){

        Z_data[i] = -D / ((C + B * pts_y[i] + A * pts_x[i]));
        X_data[i] = pts_x[i] * Z_data[i];
        Y_data[i] = pts_y[i] * Z_data[i];
    }

// Do something more

    X.clear(); X.shrink_to_fit();
    Y.clear(); Y.shrink_to_fit();
    Z.clear(); Z.shrink_to_fit();

}

int main(){

    //std::vector<cv::Point2f> input;
    Points2D* point = new Points2D();

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 1e8; i++){
        point->x.push_back(double(rand()));
        point->y.push_back(double(rand()));
    }

    triangulate_simd(point);
}
```

However, I run into a segmentation fault at `_mm256_storeu_pd(Z_data + i, result_z);` 
I am not sure why does it throw a segmentation fault, I have double checked the ranges and everything. I even set the range range of X,Y and Z vectors to make sure I am not accessing memory which has not been allocated. Could someone please point me in the right direction.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

`Z_data` holds the data pointer of an empty vector, because you used `.data()` before `.reserve()`.

This doesn't update if you later change the size (or `reserve` memory) for the vector.  That's why [the documentation says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) `reserve` invalidates iterators if the new size is greater than `capacity()` (which was originally 0 in your case).  `.data()` was probably nullptr to start with, and `.reserve()` allocated some space and updated the internal state that `.data()` returns.

Also, you are not technically allowed to write to the reserved space anyway, only to as much space as vector.size() indicates, although that often happens to work as a hack.  With a custom allocator, you can get `std::vector` to skip actually writing the memory when increasing `size` to make it fully guaranteed safe to use the space.

Comment: Oh, I suppose there is a gap in my fundamental understanding of vectors. I thought `vector.data()` would give me the pointer  to the start of the memory location and builds it upon there on. Does reserve change the base memory location ?

Comment: We can write to the reserved space I suppose

Comment: `data()` gives you a pointer to the internal data, if there is any. For an empty vector, there probably isn't. If you `reserve()` more than the current capacity, the vector will reallocate its memory, which changes the data pointer.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I will try it out. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are not _allowed_ to write to the reserved but unused space, even if we know it is there. Technically, the vector _could_ use it for some internal bookeeping.

Comment: @AtharvaDubey legally you need to either switch to `resize` or pass the desired size into the constructor of the vector. If the elements of the vector haven't had their lifetime started then modifying them is undefined behavior.